# why nResult ！= nConvertedLen，when use CComBSTR；

Tags: c++, string

```
CComBSTR wsData = (char*)pvData；
```

when constuct CComBSTR，call A2WBSTR，but sometimes nResult ！= nConvertedLen，just 1/20. why？

```
inline BSTR A2WBSTR(_In_opt_ LPCSTR lp, int nLen = -1)
{
    if (lp == NULL || nLen == 0)
        return NULL;
    USES_CONVERSION_EX;
    BSTR str = NULL;
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 6385)
    int nConvertedLen = MultiByteToWideChar(_acp_ex, 0, lp,
        nLen, NULL, NULL);
#pragma warning(pop)
    int nAllocLen = nConvertedLen;
    if (nLen == -1)
        nAllocLen -= 1;  // Don't allocate terminating '\0'
    str = ::SysAllocStringLen(NULL, nAllocLen);

    if (str != NULL)
    {
        int nResult;
        nResult = MultiByteToWideChar(_acp_ex, 0, lp, nLen, str, nConvertedLen);
        ATLASSERT(nResult == nConvertedLen);
        if(nResult != nConvertedLen)
        {
            SysFreeString(str);
            return NULL;
        }

    }
    return str;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best guess is that there are multi-threading issues involved. As you can see both `nResult` and `nConvertedLen` are results to calls to `MultiByteToWideChar` with the **same source string**. The first call is used to simply determine the length of the buffer that needs to be allocated to return the result of the conversion.

[MultiByteToWideChar Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb202786.aspx) describes the behaviour of the function when the buffer length parameter is 0:

> cchWideChar
>
> [in] Size, in wide characters, of the buffer pointed to by the
>   lpWideCharStr parameter.
>
> If this value is zero, the function returns the required buffer
>   size, in wide characters, and makes no
>   use of the lpWideCharStr buffer.

So, the only time that the two values would be different is when string pointed to by `lp` changes between to calls, most likely due to threading issues.